# How to add greek letters to a label in geom_text() label in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am trying to label the tiles in geom_tile with the Greek symbol, kappa, as follows

kappa = value

I've tried using expression() and bquote() but cannot find a way to make it work

```
df = data.frame(x = letters[1:10],y = letters[11:20], value = 1:10)

p = ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_tile()+geom_text(aes(label= paste("k = ",value,"")), color = "white")

p

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bDLv.png
```

Comment: You could try using the Unicode escape  `paste("\u03f0 =", value)`

Comment: Thanks alot!! The code for kappa is u03ba, but it worked a treat!!

Answer (score 4):

use `parse = TRUE`

also learn more about mathematical expressions used in plot by following this: `?plotmath`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(mapping = aes(label = paste('kappa', "==", value)), parse = TRUE, color = "white")
```

[image]